# magento installion on url protocol adding error

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

I just install a magento .But i have stuck in database setup and set url page. I have got error message for url protocol adding field.I added (http://localhost/magento/) .But there are not accept this value and ask me to ask protocol.What is wrong things for that. I believe "http" is protocol so i have already added protocol in url.I have removed the url validation but it does not work yet.I am getting url protocol require error .Could you help me for that.?

Comment: try with 127.0.0.1/magento/

Comment: I believe it will be due to `localhost` not being a domain

Comment: I try with 127.0.0.1 . It is okay now.Thank you @AlexColoma